# $cookies angular.js injection to controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs, cookies

can someone explain me how to inject $cookies to my angular controller? I found answers related to the same problem, but solutions dont work in my case ! here is my code:
https://gist.github.com/anonymous/f501a574ca67d4d0c2c3

file of angular-cookies.js is okay, the problem comes with appControllers.js file. Here is the error at console:

Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.3.0-beta.19/$injector/unpr?p0=%24%24cookieReaderProvider%20%3C-%20%24ookieReader%20%3C-%20%24cookies

Answer (score 0):

I think it is the angular-cookies version is not Compatible with the angularjs

make sure it is the same with the angularjs

bower.json

```
  "dependencies": {
    "angular-animate": "~1.3.14",
    "angular-route": "~1.3.14",
    "angular-ui-router": "~0.2.13",
    "angular-resource": "~1.3.14",
    "bootstrap": "~3.3.5",
    "angular": "~1.3.17",
    "fontawesome": "~4.3.0",
    "lodash": "~1.3.0",
    "toastr": "~2.1.0",
    "underscore": "~1.8.2",
    "ace-builds": "~1.1.8",
    "angular-ui-ace": "~0.2.3",
    "angular-bootstrap": "~0.12.1",
    "restangular": "~1.4.0",
    "jquery": "~1.9.1",
    "ng-file-upload-shim": "~5.1.0",
    "ng-file-upload": "~5.1.0",
    "simple-line-icons": "~1.0.0",
    "angular-ui-grid": "~3.0.1",
    "angular-cookies": "~1.3.17"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "angular": "1.3.17"
  }
}
```